# php regex, extract like phone number regex from html documents

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract a specific information from different html pages. Basically the information is a 10 digits number which may have different forms such :

```
000-000-0000
000 - 000 - 0000
0000000000
```

```
please note that 000 - 000 - 0000000 is not a valid phone number so it should not extract the number if it contains any additional digits
```

I would appreciate any help to create the perfect regex working on all the 3 situations . So far I could make it work only for the last one (the simplest one ).

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I originally closed the incorrect duplicate. Are you per chance trying to match phone numbers inside of (X)HTML tags?

Comment: It appears you've downvoted every answer that didn't do exactly what you're looking for. This will discourage people from trying to help you, especially in regex questions which are easy to get wrong. You've also changed your question since posting it; your 000 - 000 - 0000000 counterexample was not in the first edit, so @Jeff's answer satisfies the original requirement. I notice he still has a downvote. I'm not saying this out of concern for my own downvote, more to help you and the general health of the site.

Answer (score 5):

This will match on all three examples you listed.

```
(\d{3}\s*-?\s*\d{3}\s*-?\s*\d{4})
```

Comment: +1 Much more concise than mine.  Guess I need to brush up on my regex-foo :)

Comment: its basically the same thing with a few less unnecessary characters. i love me some regex.

Comment: ya I couldn't remember if - was a special char or not, so i took the safe route.

Comment: the regex is not really perfect .. it finds 212-642-288455 as valid (extracts 212-642-2884)

Comment: Perfection is rare, especially in regex. +1.

Comment: @Michael i dont believe the phone part of the post was part of the original post. certainly there are issues with my regex when matching on phone numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good starting point:

```
<?php 

// all on one line... 
$regex = '/^(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?([2-9]\d{2})(?:(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?$/';

// or broken up 
$regex = '/^(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?([2-9]\d{2})' 
        .'(?:(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})' 
        .'[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?$/'; 

?>
```

Note the non-capturing subpatterns (which look like `(?:stuff)`). That makes formatting easy:

```
<?php 

$formatted = preg_replace($regex, '($1) $2-$3 ext. $4', $phoneNumber); 

// or, provided you use the $matches argument in preg_match 

$formatted = "($matches[1]) $matches[2]-$matches[3]"; 
if ($matches[4]) $formatted .= " $matches[4]"; 

?>
```

And some example results for you:

```
520-555-5542 :: MATCH 
520.555.5542 :: MATCH 
5205555542 :: MATCH 
520 555 5542 :: MATCH 
520) 555-5542 :: FAIL 
(520 555-5542 :: FAIL 
(520)555-5542 :: MATCH 
(520) 555-5542 :: MATCH 
(520) 555 5542 :: MATCH 
520-555.5542 :: MATCH 
520 555-0555 :: MATCH 
(520)5555542 :: MATCH 
520.555-4523 :: MATCH 
19991114444 :: FAIL 
19995554444 :: MATCH 
514 555 1231 :: MATCH 
1 555 555 5555 :: MATCH 
1.555.555.5555 :: MATCH 
1-555-555-5555 :: MATCH 
520-555-5542 ext.123 :: MATCH 
520.555.5542 EXT 123 :: MATCH 
5205555542 Ext. 7712 :: MATCH 
520 555 5542 ext 5 :: MATCH 
520) 555-5542 :: FAIL 
(520 555-5542 :: FAIL 
(520)555-5542 ext .4 :: FAIL 
(512) 555-1234 ext. 123 :: MATCH 
1(555)555-5555 :: MATCH
```

You'll probably get a lot of false positives if you allow spaces and dashes like you're suggesting.

Comment: It looks fine to me, and you've done some pretty exhaustive testing, which is great. +1.

Comment: Very nice!  Just had to comment on the quality of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

`\b[0-9]{3}\s*[-]?\s*[0-9]{3}\s*[-]?\s*[0-9]{4}\b`

**Edit**

Added word boundaries.

Comment: the regex is not really perfect .. it finds 212-642-288455 as valid (extracts 212-642-2884) –

Comment: You don't need the [] around `-`, but it should work anyway. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider other delimiters besides hyphens, not to mention parentheses.

```
(?:1\s*?[-.]?\s*)?(?:\(\s*d{3}\s*\)|d{3})\s*?[-.]?\s*\d{3}\s*?[-.]?\s*\d{4}\b
```

Okay, maybe that's more comprehensive than you need, but really this can get as complicated as you like. You can expand it to look for international phone numbers, extensions, and so forth, but that might not be worth it for you.

Comment: I think it's not working at all ... $htmlContent = "834-343-3434";
$pattern = "/(?:1\s*?[-.]?\s*)?(?:\(\\s*d{3}\s*\)|d{3})\s*?[-.]?\s*\d{3}\s*?[-.]?\s*\d{4}\b/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $htmlContent, $matches);
print_r($matches);

Comment: @Michael: I'm not sure how \\s got in there. Edited. FYI, it's usually considered bad form to downvote something that was an honest attempt but failed, unless the answer is very clearly wrongheaded or counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
preg_match_all("/\+?[0-9][\d-\()-\s+]{5,12}[1-9]/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```