# php regex , extract phone number from text/html

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regex, extract like phone number regex from html documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111029/php-regex-extract-like-phone-number-regex-from-html-documents)

I'm trying to extract phone numbers from different html pages. Basically the information is a 10 digits number which may have different forms such :

```
000-000-0000
000 - 000 - 0000
0000000000
```

```
please note that 000 - 000 - 0000000 is not a valid phone number so it should not extract the number if it contains any additional digits
```

I would appreciate any help to create the perfect regex working on all the 3 situations . So far I could make it work only for the last one (the simplest one ).

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111029/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111029/)

Comment: Yeah, asking the same exact question twice is not cool.

Comment: yeah you are right but not even the 2nd time I didn't get a correct answer

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good starting point:

```
<?php 

// all on one line... 
$regex = '/^(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?([2-9]\d{2})(?:(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?$/';

// or broken up 
$regex = '/^(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?([2-9]\d{2})' 
        .'(?:(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})' 
        .'[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?$/'; 

?>
```

Note the non-capturing subpatterns (which look like `(?:stuff)`). That makes formatting easy:

```
<?php 

$formatted = preg_replace($regex, '($1) $2-$3 ext. $4', $phoneNumber); 

// or, provided you use the $matches argument in preg_match 

$formatted = "($matches[1]) $matches[2]-$matches[3]"; 
if ($matches[4]) $formatted .= " $matches[4]"; 

?>
```

And some example results for you:

```
520-555-5542 :: MATCH 
520.555.5542 :: MATCH 
5205555542 :: MATCH 
520 555 5542 :: MATCH 
520) 555-5542 :: FAIL 
(520 555-5542 :: FAIL 
(520)555-5542 :: MATCH 
(520) 555-5542 :: MATCH 
(520) 555 5542 :: MATCH 
520-555.5542 :: MATCH 
520 555-0555 :: MATCH 
(520)5555542 :: MATCH 
520.555-4523 :: MATCH 
19991114444 :: FAIL 
19995554444 :: MATCH 
514 555 1231 :: MATCH 
1 555 555 5555 :: MATCH 
1.555.555.5555 :: MATCH 
1-555-555-5555 :: MATCH 
520-555-5542 ext.123 :: MATCH 
520.555.5542 EXT 123 :: MATCH 
5205555542 Ext. 7712 :: MATCH 
520 555 5542 ext 5 :: MATCH 
520) 555-5542 :: FAIL 
(520 555-5542 :: FAIL 
(520)555-5542 ext .4 :: FAIL 
(512) 555-1234 ext. 123 :: MATCH 
1(555)555-5555 :: MATCH
```

You'll probably get a lot of false positives if you allow spaces and dashes like you're suggesting.

Comment: the only issue is that I don't really need 1(555)555-5555 to match. As I said I need 10 digits only not 11 .

Comment: @Michael So drop the first `(?:1(?:[. -])?)?` out of the regex. I don't see how it'd hurt to match something that with higher qualification, though, especially when the subpatterns do all the work of giving you the area code, prefix and line number.

Comment: `19991114444 :: FAIL` / `19995554444 :: MATCH`  why does that one fail?

Comment: @jnpcl Because prefixes that start with 1 are invalid.

Comment: @coreyward: Interesting.. I wasn't aware of that particular rule for phone numbers.

Comment: @jnpcl Not all numbers, but those following the North American Numbering Plan (which is what this pattern targets). :)

Comment: the pattern doesn't work anyway when html tags appear ...e.g if we have  <pre style="font-size: 9pt;"><tt>293-232-2323  it doesn't get the phone number ... so it's useless

Comment: @Michael I'm glad you're not getting use out of it if that's the attitude you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow unlimited combinations of exactly 10 digits, then this will do the trick:

```
^\D?((?:\d\D*){10})$
```

Comment: is not working ... I tried it with the following content <pre style="font-size: 9pt;"><tt>293-232-2323