# PHP regular expression for given condition

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regex , extract phone number from text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112520/php-regex-extract-phone-number-from-text-html)

I have following requirement. There is a phone number field.

- Its length should be between 8 and 10
- It can contain only _ and white spaces
- First and last elements should be digits
- _ and white spaces should be in between 2 digits

Can I write a regular expression to validate the above things using php?

Example for valid entry: 231_901 347
Example for invalid entry: _123 567, 345__123

Also if possible, can you please write down the preg_match expression.

Here is the code which I tried:

```
$subject = "_012_345 69";
$pattern = '/[\d]{1}.[\d\s_]{5,10}.[\d]{1}$/';
$matches = preg_match($pattern, $subject);
echo($matches);
```

It should return 0 but it returns 1.

Comment: Yes, yes you can.

Comment: Jep. validation can be done through php.

Comment: I hope [this post][1] will help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112520/php-regex-extract-phone-number-from-text-html

Comment: Try a simple search on here. I searched for "php validate phone number" and came up with some nice answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+validate+phone+number

Comment: please mention the reason for Invalid entry in OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^(?=.{8,10}$)\d+(?:[ _]\d+)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^              # Start of string
 (?=.{8,10}$)  # Assert length 8-10
 \d+           # One or more digits
 (?:           # followed by
  [ _]         #  one space or underscore
  \d+          #  one or more digits
 )*            # zero or more times.           
$              # End of string
```

Comment: @Gabber: You're probably right; I misunderstood his last requirement.

Comment: @TimPietzcker not so sure anymore... 
`12 23 12 12 12` is 10 digits but its length is 14 => not a good match. I think the OP meant that he needs 8-10 *digits*, not characters, otherwise this would lead to a probably wrong number of digits varying from `1 2 2 3 1` (5) to `1234567890` (10)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern

```
^(?=.{8,10}$)(?=\d)(?=.*\d$)(?:\d|(?<=\d)[\s_](?=\d))+$
```

---

***Explanation >>***

```
^
```

Start if line/string

```
(?=.{8,10}$)
```

String size is 8-10 characters

```
(?=\d)
```

First character is digit

```
(?=.*\d$)
```

Last character is digit

```
(?:\d|(?<=\d)[\s_](?=\d))+
```

Allowed characters are (a) digits or (b) whitespace or underscore between digits

```
$
```

End of line/string

Answer (score 0):

This meets all your requirements as I understand them:

```
^(?:\d[ _]*){7,9}\d$
```

As for those false positives you're getting, you just left off the start anchor (`^`).  But even with anchor added it matches things like

```
1_________2
```

and

```
01234567890123
```

I'm assuming those are invalid because you meant there have to be eight to ten *digits*, not that the overall length should be eight to ten.